# how to convert an existing gwt application in eclipse to maven project

Tags: gwt, maven, migrate

is there any reference website or tutorial? I see some website for migrate java project to maven project, some website for new gwt application using maven, but no website for migrate existing gwt application in eclipse project to maven project.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

1. Right click on the project.
2. Focus on **Configure** in menu.
3. Select option **Convert to Maven Project**.

And if that doesn't work for you. I suggest you to create new maven project and then move all your code there step by step.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Comment: What problem you are facing now?